# Why is a cell with a value seen as being null (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aspose-cells

I need to loop through a PivotTable and colorize certain ranges. I'm trying to do that with the following code:

```
private void ColorizeContractItemBlocks(List<string> contractItemDescs)
{
    int FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW = 7;
    int DESCRIPTION_COL = 0;
    int ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS = 4;
    var pivot = pivotTableSheet.PivotTables[0];
    // DataBodyRange returns CellArea that represents range between the header row & insert row
    var dataBodyRange = pivot.DataBodyRange;
    int currentRowBeingExamined = FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW;
    int rowsUsed = dataBodyRange.EndRow;
    // Loop through PivotTable data, colorizing contract items
    while (currentRowBeingExamined < rowsUsed)
    {
        Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, DESCRIPTION_COL];
        String desc = descriptionCell.Value.ToString();
        if (contractItemDescs.Contains(desc))
        {
            // args are firstRow, firstColumn, totalRows, totalColumns
            Range rangeToColorize = pivotTableSheet.Cells.CreateRange(
                currentRowBeingExamined, 0,
                ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS, _grandTotalsColumnPivotTable + 1);
            Style style = workBook.Styles[workBook.Styles.Add()];
            style.BackgroundColor = CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR;
            StyleFlag styleFlag = new StyleFlag();
            styleFlag.All = true;
            rangeToColorize.ApplyStyle(style, styleFlag);
        }
        currentRowBeingExamined = currentRowBeingExamined + ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it crashes on the second line below because "descriptionCell" is considered to be a null value:

```
Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, DESCRIPTION_COL];
String desc = descriptionCell.Value.ToString();
```

It crashes the first time through the loop, when the value of currentRowBeingExamined is 7. Keeping in mind that Aspose Cells rows and columns are 0-based, you can see that "A8" (In spreadsheet parlance), which corresponds to row 7, column 0, according to Aspose Cells' take on it, does indeed have a value, namely, "ANISE, FENNEL 12 CT":

[image]

Stepping through it, I see, "*A8; ValueType: IsNull*"

So why is the assignment to descriptionCell null rather than "ANISE, FENNEL 12 CT"?

Note: ColorizeContractItemBlocks() is called after the PivotTable has been generated. If I comment out the call to ColorizeContractItemBlocks(), the spreadsheet is generated, with the PivotTable on it, as you can see in the screenshot above.

### UPDATE

Just for the Hec Ramsey of it, I tried grabbing one row down and one column to the right:

```
Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[8, 1]; // should be "Sum of TotalPrice"
Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[7, 1]; // should be "Sum of TotalQty"
```

...but both are also null; is *anything* in the PivotTable viewed as not null?

### UPDATE 2

I thought I was on to something (rather than on something) when I tried this:

```
Cell descCell = pivot.GetCellByDisplayName("A8");
```

...but it was also struck down by the apostles of nullification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These calls must be added outside the while loop:

```
pivot.RefreshData();
pivot.CalculateData();
```